# cmd exited with error code 1

Tags: cmd, remote-access, psexec

I am trying to search a file on remote PC using PSEXEC, however I am getting the above mentioned error.

Can any please suggest any change in the command or some thing else, that can assist in making it work.
Online search suggests that this isn't the issue of PSEXEC, instead is caused by explorer.exe on remote host.

I have added picture of my result. I have tried the command with quotes on file name and without. both have same error.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command `dir` exists with code 1 and message "File Not Found".
Because you run `cmd` with param `/c` than it return same error code like `dir` and it is equal 1.

It is correct behaviour.

If you want to find a file, than use command `where /r c:\ d.txt`. This command was added in Windows 7.

Or use `dir /S /P "d.txt"` for older OS

Comment: is there a way if I can expand my search, i mean right now it searches for file in C: drive only, Can I use some wild card for drive letter?

My search leads me to use of /D parameter, but that is only for For Loop. Further documentation points out that this Where takes C: as current and starts search from here,

Answer (score 3):

Open Registry Editor by pressing **windows+r**
then type **regedit** and press enter
now in the search bar paste the below line

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\`

If you can see in the picture using the link
[Underlined mark is important don't insert any other value in the data of that particular registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6dq5.png).

**Here if you filed many registry values then delete all of them except the default one as they are the main reason for the error code 1 shown by the command prompt.
So after removing all of them.**

> Edit the default registry value and in 'data' insert cmd and save it

Your problem is solved!!
if not then clear the data of the default registry.

Comment: How in the name of does one find that solution? I had an entry "AutoRun" with value "if exists" and as soon as I deleted it, the cmd command (and subsequently flutter for some reason) worked again. Even without the cmd as default. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is also easy to use PowerShell and not need psexec.

```
Invoke-Command HOST01 { & cmd.exe /C dir D:\Users\lit\d.txt }
```

It should be written in .ps1 scripts with parameter names specified.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName HOST01 -ScriptBlock { & cmd.exe /C dir D:\Users\lit\d.txt }
```

See also:

```
help Enable-PSRemoting
help about_Remote
help about_Remote_FAQ
```